# Connecting MySQL using ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have an ASP Website, my problem is how to connect the database using asp.

I have a paid hosting in bravehost/bravenet, which can be access through phpWebAdmin. when I am connecting using the mysql.connection in vs i am having an exception "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." I inputted correct database name, server, username, etc.

While searching the net, I have read that some hosting disable the "remote access" (I forgot the term).

Can you suggest possible steps to connect my asp to mysql? Is it possible to connect asp to php so the php script will be the one who will retrieve, save, update the database?

Answer (score 0):

Are your website and your database on the same webserver?  If they are then remote connections shouldn't be a problem, just use "localhost" in your connection string

If you can connect with a php script then you should be able to connect via an asp script on the same server.  The standard way to connect to MySQL through classic ASP is with the MyODBC driver.  Is this driver installed on your server, it isn't installed on IIS by default?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can post your data on PHP pages and php pages can do rest of operation.

It is same like you post data on ASP page.

you just need to change action="xxx.php" in  tag.